# How do I stop a Navigation link kicking the user out after they make changes in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've made a search bar where the user can search for and then click on different events (similar to a calendar) however it kicks the user out of the event view if they make any changes to it / edit it

this is the code for the search bar:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: View {
    @Binding var dates: [DatesInfo]
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            ForEach($dates, id: \.id) { $date in
                if (date.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())){
                    //when the user is searching
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(thisDate: $date)
                    } label: {
                        Text(date.title)
                    }
                }

                else {
                    //if they aren't searching
                    if (searchText.isEmpty){
                        NavigationLink {
                            DetailView(thisDate: $date)
                        } label: {
                            Text(date.title)
                        }
                    }
                }  
            } 
        }  
    } 
}
```

in the past it's because I've used `id: \.self` but as that isn't the case here I'm not sure what's causing this issue

Comment: for a `NavigationLink` to work, you need to enclose it in a `NavigationStack`

Comment: SwiftUI is all about identity, you have to find which identity is triggering, this is one of those things that can’t be answered without a full example.